# How to generate the p12 file for my phonegap build?

Tags: ios, openssl, phonegap-build

My company made a developer certificate on the Apple Developer platform. 
At this point I need to link a key file to my iOS build in Phonegap.

I'm trying to generate this key file where I need the `.p12` file and the `provisioning profile` file. I've got myself the `provisioning profile` file, but I can't seem to generate the `.p12` file.

I'm using Openssl to generate my files and I tried this command to generate the last file:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey ios.key -in ios_development.pem -out ios_development.p12
Enter pass phrase for ios.key: *********
No certificate matches private key
```

What exactly am I doing wrong here? Can I find the private key on the [developer.apple.com](http://developer.apple.com) website?

UPDATE: here are the steps I'm performing to get to this problem:

1. Generate private key: `openssl genrsa -des3 -out ios.key 2048` and enter a password `pass123`
2. Generate CSR file: `openssl req -new -key ios.key -out ios.csr -subj "/emailAddress=info@company.com, CN=company, C=BE"` and enter the password from the private key `pass123`
3. Go to your Apple Developer iOS Provisioning Portal and download the development certificate `.cer` file
4. Convert the certificate to a PEM file: `openssl x509 -in ios_development.cer -inform DER -out ios_development.pem -outform PEM`
5. Generate the P12 file using the private key (ios.key) and the iOS development certificate (ios_development.pem): `openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey ios.key -in ios_development.pem -out ios_development.p12` and enter the password from the private key `pass123`
6. Error message: `No certificate matches private key`

Comment: do you have keychain in your system?

Comment: No I'm using Windows for this, so I don't think I have keychain

Comment: see this :https://www.google.co.in/search?q=generate+.12+file+in+window+os&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&gfe_rd=cr&ei=yApMV_rFKJHT8gfMx4uAAw#q=in+windows+how+to+generate+p12+certificate

Comment: I followed all of the possible steps I need to go through, but I keep ending up with the `No certificate matches private key` message when I try to generate the p12 file.

Comment: I've also added my steps in the original post for more details

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Apple Stack Exchange](http://apple.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Answer (score 1):

-> First of all download **Developer Certificate** from your **Apple Developer** account. After that double click the .cer file and install it to keychain Login.

-> You can open KeyChain Acccess on your Mac , Applications>Utilities>Keychain Access

-> Now export the certificate file and private key files separately as cert.p12 and key.p12 by right clicking the certificates.
￼ ￼[image]

Comment: If you don't have mac pc then see this link. hope it will help you http://www.joshmorony.com/how-to-create-an-ios-provisioning-profile-and-p12-with-windows/

Comment: I still end up getting the `No certificate matches private key` message in the end. Like I said, we have a certificate ready on the developer.apple.com website, but I've got a feeling I don't need to generate a new private key.

Comment: have you downloaded developer cerficate from apple developer account?